# Формирование маркированного списка с якорями по заголовкам

Tags: javascript, jquery

Возможно ли прочитать в блоке заголовки? Пример кода:

```
<div class="cont">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="1">Заголовок 1</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="2">Заголовок 2</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="3">Заголовок 3</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
</div>
```

После чего сформировать маркированный список с якорями, отправляющими к этим заголовкам по `id`. По итогу создать список после заголовка `h2`, привязываясь только к заголовкам `h3`, чтоб вышло вот так:

```
<div class="cont">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
    <ul class="anchor">
        <li><a href="#1" title="Заголовок 1" rel="nofollow">Заголовок 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#2" title="Заголовок 2" rel="nofollow">Заголовок 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#3" title="Заголовок 3" rel="nofollow">Заголовок 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="1">Заголовок 1</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="2">Заголовок 2</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="3">Заголовок 3</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
</div>
```

Так же, интересует мнение о сложности решения, скорости загрузки и т.д.. Стоит ли так заморачиваться при большом количестве материала или все же руками формировать быстрый переход?

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName('h3')` вернет массив заголовков. Дальше его можно пробежаться и сформировать ссылки по желаемому принципу

Comment: @DNS насколько я понимаю, то массив будет без id заголовков. Как потом их раскидать по созданному списку? Можно ли создать массив такого вида `{"1": "Заголовок 1", "2": "Заголовок 2", ... }` собрав id и сам заголовок из тегов h3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="cont">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="1">Заголовок 1</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="2">Заголовок 2</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="3">Заголовок 3</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
</div>

<p id='out'></p>

<script>
var a=document.getElementsByTagName('h3');
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    window.out.innerHTML+=a[i].id+', '+a[i].innerHTML+'<br>';
</script>
```

Пример как можно добраться до ид и текста. Обвязку, надеюсь, сделаете без проблем

--Добавил---

Чтобы получить как в вопросе

```
<div class="cont">
    <h2>Заголовок</h2>
    <ul class="anchor" id='anc'>

    </ul>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="1">Заголовок 1</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="2">Заголовок 2</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
    <h3 id="3">Заголовок 3</h3>
    <p>Текст</p>
</div>

<script>
var a=document.getElementsByTagName('h3'),b='';
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
    b+='<li><a href="#'+a[i].id+'" title="'+a[i].innerHTML+'" rel="nofollow">'+a[i].innerHTML+'</a></li>';
window.anc.innerHTML = b;
</script>
```

Comment: О, а я как раз хотел поблагодарить за первую часть. Сделал немного иначе, но, все же, воспользуюсь вашим вариантом, так как он вышел куда короче. Спасибо большое!

Comment: А можно ли в вашем примере добавить именно создание списка, а не вписывание в существующий тег? И проверку тегов. Например, если нет тегов h3 с id, то создание списка не происходит. [Вот](http://codepen.io/Giryayev/pen/WpdLVB) вариант который я сделал, но, он весьма громоздкий вышел.

Comment: можно, конечно. С одной стороны список без элементов не отображается, но если очень нужно именно создавать - пишите или в `innerHTML` родителя, или создавайте "ребенка". Проверку можно делать используя [hasAttribute()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_hasattribute.asp). В довесок я недолюбливаю jQuery. Если нужна помощь именно в этой области - я не эксперт

Comment: Спасибо за hasAttribute, в общем-то все уже сделал. Только почему-то не выходит проверку заголовков именно по элементу делать, а не по всему документу. Впрочем, это не очень важно. Еще раз спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Сейчас быстро не приходит в голову, как красиво сделать проверку внутри отдельных эл-тов. Лучше всего, дать заголовкам одинаковые имена `name=` внутри одного блока и искать по именам `getElementsByName()`. Тогда конфликтов с другими блоками быть не должно